# How to print a presentable layout in jquery?

Tags: jquery, printing

Below is the structure I want to print out into presentable layout, by adding header, footer and also by retaining jquery event values in the cash and balance textboxes.

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns" id="print_item">
            <div class="left_content">
                <p><strong><u>Checkout</u></strong></p>
                <ul class="large-block-grid-1">
                    <li style="border-bottom: 1px solid #222;margin-bottom: 10px;"><div class="large-4 columns">Item Name</div>
                        <div class="large-1 columns">Qty</div>
                        <div class="large-4 columns">Price Subtotal</div>
                        <div class="large-3 columns">Action</div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                 <ul id="show-cart" class="large-block-grid-1">
                <li>???????</li>

                </ul>

                <!--agent items starts-->
                 <div id="agent">

                 </div>
                <!--agent items ends-->

            <div>You have <span id="count-cart">X</span> items in your cart</div>
            <br/>
            <div>Total Cart:RM <span id="total-cart"></span></div>
            <br/>
            <div>Paid:RM <input type="text" id="cash" /></div>
            <br/>
            <div>Balance:RM <input type="text" id="balance" /></div>
            <ul class="large-block-grid-3">
                <li><button id="continue-cart">Continue Shopping</button></li>
                <li><button id="submit-cart">Submit Cart</button></li>
                <li><button id="print-cart">Print Invoice</button>  </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

Script to print:

```
//print data
             $("#print-cart").click(function(event){
                printData()
             });
                function printData() {
                    var divToPrint = document.getElementById("print_item");
                    newWin = window.open("");
                    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
                    newWin.print();
                    newWin.close();
                }
```

And this prints out as below which is not attractive also the last two textboxes lost their values:
[image]

But I wish to print out something like this which is also current shopping cart:
If I want to pass additional value like company name to be displayed in the header, is it possible?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

With document.write you override all html you previously had. Thus, you are losing all previously loaded javascript and css.
instead of:

```
newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
```

try:

```
newWin.document.getElementById('some id').append(the div you want to add)
```

But add also the rest of the css and js you expect to have.

Comment: with this unable to print